# How to get a String out of a text file with Qt Libraries

Tags: c++, qt, text, qstring

I want to get some Strings out of a text file. I know how to get the whole String of a text file with

```
QTextStream Stream (GEO); 
QString text;    
 do    
{    
text = Stream.readLine();  

}
while(!text.isNull());
```

That works fine to get all the text under the QString text, but I just need some specific strings out of the text,schematically like:

```
if the text "start" appears in the Qstring text (or the QTextStream Stream) 

save the following text under QString First

until the text "end" appears
```

Can someone tell me how to do this or maybe even give me a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can use is to get the indexes of the "start" and "end" with  indexOf() and the just use:

```
QString x = "start some text here end";
QString s = "start";
QString e = "end"
int start = x.indexOf(s, 0, Qt::CaseInsensitive);  // returns the first encounter of the string 
int end = x.indexOf(e, Qt::CaseInsensitive);  // returns 21

if(start != -1) // we found it
    QString y = x.mid(start + s.length(), end);
```

or midRef if you dont want to create a new list. You might have to handle "end" aswell, otherwise you might go from 0 to -1 which wouldnt return anything. Maybe (end > start ? end : start)

Edit: Nevermind. If end == -1 that just means that it will return everything until the end (per default the second parameter is -1). If you don't want this you can go with my example instead and use some kind of if-statement when choosing the "end"

Edit: Noticed that I missread the doc and this will def. work:

```
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QString x = "start some text here end";
    QString s = "start";
    QString e = "end";
    int start = x.indexOf(s, 0, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 
    int end = x.indexOf(e, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 

    if(start != -1){ // we found it
        QString y = x.mid(start + s.length(), ((end - (start + s.length())) > -1 ? (end - (start + s.length())) : -1)); // if you dont wanna pass in a number less than -1
        or
        QString y = x.mid(start + s.length(), (end - (start + s.length()))); // should not be any issues passing in a number less than -1, still works

        qDebug() << y << (start + s.length()) << (end - (start + s.length()));
    }
}
```

This produces the following resoults. The last two numbers are where "start" ends and "end" begins.

> x = "start some text here end" => " some text here " 5 16
>
> x = " some text here end" => no outprint
>
> x = "testing start start some text here end" => " start some text here " 13 22
>
> x = "testing start start some text here" => " start some text here" 13 -14

Or you can do it by using regEx. Wrote a very simple snippet here for you:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRegExp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QRegExp rxlen("(start)(.*(?=$|end))");
    rxlen.setMinimal(true); // it's lazy which means that if it finds "end" it stops and not trying to find "$" which is the end of the string 
    int pos = rxlen.indexIn("test start testing some text start here fdsfdsfdsend test ");

    if (pos > -1) { // if the string matched, which means that "start" will be in it, followed by a string 
        qDebug() <<  rxlen.cap(2); // " testing some text start here fdsfdsfds" 
    }
}
```

This works even if you done have "end" in the end, then it just parse to the end of the line. Enjoy!

Comment: thx for the answer. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#mid I just have a problem with the "end", because in the documentary it is written that the second argument (n -> in your example "end") is the number of characters returned started from the first argument "start + s.length()". So if your first argument is the start position/index which is ok, the second will be the number of characters of a string equal to the index/position of "end". Could you tell me how to fix the problem with the end? Otherwise really fine idea with the "s.length()" greetings

Comment: Ok, if I am right for the second argument "end -(start+s.length)" should work. i will test this when I have time the next days and after that accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. read my editted version. Also tested it and provided you with output